# Postgres files and pages

Tags: postgresql, storage

I got confused between files and pages in postgres, I have table for 700 MG and i find this file in base/5, so if i have the whole file with the actual size where's is pages then ?!

I try to understand the storage manager of postgres to know how to maximize the sequential access, while I'm trying to use postgres as a data warehouse.

Comment: Read [Storage](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage.html) in particular [File layout](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-file-layout.html)

Comment: Pages are stored in files - search for queries relating tables to files, then navigate your file system to find the file. With 700MB, you should have one large data file constaining a few thousand pages (700MB/8K - 8K being the size of a page) - PostgreSQL "amalgamates" pages by 1GB "extents" (Oracle terminology). This question is too broad and would require an essay type answer to fully cover the topic - do some reading and come back to us if you have more specific questions/issues/problems.

Answer (score 2):

Each table is split into *segments* (files) of 1GB. All segments except the last one are exactly 1GB in size. If your table has less than 1GB, it will have only a single file. (Apart from this *main fork", there may be some additional, smaller files — the free space map, the visibility map and the initialization fork for unlogged tables — but they don't concern us here.)

Each file is split into pages of 8kB each. A 1GB segment contains exactly 131072 such pages.